# Is there any way of taking a swiffy animation and making it as a div background-image?

Tags: css, html

I want to work over the image, but instead it just gets forced down below any content.

Comment: What is the image's end format? Is it just a static image?

Comment: No it's an animation that I converted from swf at http://www.google.com/doubleclick/studio/swiffy/

Answer (score 0):

[Swiffy animations](http://www.google.com/doubleclick/studio/swiffy/gallery.html) are not images. CSS `background-image` requires an image, as the property name implies. So the answer is **no**, it's not possible.

Comment: So does that mean that the only way to make animated backgrounds is using a .gif image? I don't want to be limited to just 256 colours :(

Comment: I'm not even sure that animated GIFs work as background-images. But you can always use your animation as an absolutely positioned div with a z-index lower than the other contents. It will be an animated background, but not using CSS `background-image`.

Comment: Well, you could actually use the `content` css tag to specify that each div of a given class would have the image load as it's background. It wouldn't actually be a "background" but you could make it appear to be.